# How to call `id` from database?

Tags: php, html, mysql

i have created a form to update name into database, i have created two tables `first_name` and `last_name` into database, have look once here is my code:

```
$sql="
CREATE TABLE admin
(
id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
first_name VARCHAR(100),
last_name VARCHAR(100),
)";
```

Now i have created to update form here:

```
<div class="box">
    <h1 style="font-family: consolas">Change your name</h1><hr>
    <div id="change_name">
        <label><strong>Your current name: </strong></label>
        <?php
        include('change_setting_db.php');

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo $row['first_name']." ".$row['last_name'];
        }
        ?><br><br>

        <form method="post" action="do_update_name.php">
        <label><strong>First name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
        <label><strong>Last name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </div>

</div>
```

and here is my `do_update_name.php` file:

```
<?php
$firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
$lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
$id=$_GET['id'];

$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","Bhawanku", "members");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$update =mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE admin SET first_name='$firstname' AND  last_name='$lastname' WHERE id='$id' ");
if($update){
    echo "Successfully created!!";
}
?>
```

Now problem is when i put new name and do submit, it shows an error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\Users\Raj\PhpstormProjects\...\new do_update_name.php on line 4
Successfully created!!
```

Comment: you want to update or insert new record ??

Comment: `$_GET['id'];` seems undefined?

Comment: **warning** your code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: Have you actually `INSERT`ed any records into that table? You can't `UPDATE` records that don't exist. Plus, you don't `AND` field updates with an update query. it's `UPDATE ... SET field=value, field=value, field=value, etc...`

Comment: where to use `$_GET['id']` into do_update_name.php file??

Comment: yes i have already inserted a name....

Comment: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation to accomplish this because you will probably create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_GET` or `$_POST` data directly in a query.

Comment: I'm a beginner so i'll take care of such stupid `SQL INJECTION`

Answer (score 1):

```
<form method="post" action="do_update_name.php">
        <label><strong>First name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
        <label><strong>Last name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

You have to add the ID here, so the other side can pick up the $_GET parameter ['id']
For example:

```
<form method="post" action="do_update_name.php?id=1">
        <label><strong>First name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name">
        <label><strong>Last name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

Comment: sorry but i don't understand

Comment: You have the 1 site where you say

$id = $_GET['id']

but you are NOT sending any id variable.

Comment: So you add in the action:

action="do_update_name.php?id=1

Like this, your other document can receive the $_GET['id'] parameter, put it into $id and your query works.

Comment: You can also get from mysql the value of "id" selecting 'id' field in query and use: `$row['id']` in your action instead of `?id=1` use: `?id=$row['id']`

Comment: But then u will have to create a form for each of those records =)

Comment: Your code is working man but there is a new problem ..it's showing into database `first_name`: 0 and `last_name`: Arora when i update my name as "Mohit sharma" and my previous inserted name is "Rajendra Arora"

Comment: Maybe your column name isnt first_name but firstname or something like that?

Comment: You can give me accepted answer though, when this solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

HTML form with id in input type hidden

```
<div class="box">
    <h1 style="font-family: consolas">Change your name</h1><hr>
    <div id="change_name">
        <label><strong>Your current name: </strong></label>
        <?php
        include('change_setting_db.php');

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $id = $row['id'];
            $first_name = $row['first_name'];
            $last_name = $row['last_name'];
            echo $id.") ".$first_name." ".$last_name;
        }
        ?>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form method="post" action="do_update_name.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id;?>">
        <label><strong>First name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $first_name;?>">
        <label><strong>Last name: </strong></label>
        <input type="text" name="last_name" value="<?php echo $last_name;?>">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
```

PHP code with $_POST['id']

```
<?php
$firstname=$_POST['first_name'];
$lastname=$_POST['last_name'];
$id=$_POST['id'];

…
?>
```

Comment: Your closing the loop with $row before. so the $row variables in your form will always be the last element.

Comment: Selecting a specific line like: `where id = 4` in the SQL query, it's works well.

Comment: You code is working fine but when put name as "Mohit sharma" it shows into database as see this pic [click here](http://postimg.org/image/jp2fy1yy7/)

Comment: Its not possible, that this works as expected.. $id = $row['id']; your putting $row['id'] on the variable $id and echo it. But AFTEr the loop, it will always be the LAST entry saved in $id.

Comment: This will always update the last entry in the database, which gets fetched out of the Database.

Comment: Query must be for user_id #4: `SELECT id, firstname, lastname FROM table WHERE id = 4`

So we update only user_id #4.

Comment: You always update the LAST entry of the DB. yeah your right. But in the end, you should be able to say who you wanna update, or not?

Comment: I'm not sure, what the thread opener wants to achieve though. but this will always update the last entry in the database, im not quite sure if this is that what he wants to achieve

Comment: But it's not updating my database, message shows successfully but it shows into database `first_name` as 0??? can you tell me whats going on??

Comment: var_dump($firstname) just  before the query, if it says 0 or null, your sending your data wrong. otherwise its the query.